# Model-View-Controller and Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Is the model-view-controller-pattern commonly used in Java?
I heard, that it's common to use just 2 components of it, so that the view and the controller are only 1 component, communicating with the model.

Comment: See also [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question may be too wide to answer, but, to make things clear to you:

- The MVC pattern is used on many popular java web frameworks, also the MVC model 2 is kind of popular.
- If you're thinking on mobile applications, then Android uses the MVC pattern as well with well defined roles for the views and the controllers.
- If you're thinking on desktop applications, there are some swing frameworks that as well use the MVC pattern.

So in short, the answer to your question is: Yes, the MVC pattern is widely used in java and normally the views and the controllers have their own roles, maybe in swing that concept is kind of mixed but in other type of applications not so much.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very common in Java.

In JavaEE it can be as simple as a JavaBean (model) constructed by a javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet (servlet, controller) and forwarded as a request attribute to a JSP page (view) which renders it in a browser friendly format such as HTML. There are also a dizzying assortment of frameworks - some standard, others open-source, and also some proprietary - all seeking the holy grail of clean MVC development typically with syntactic sugar to reduce complexity or increase developer productivity. Some big examples are [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org) and [JavaServerFaces (JSF)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/api/). Wikipedia has a decent rundown of [Java MVC frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java).

In JavaSE, a GUI application designed using MVC would have access to rich techniques such as listeners to communicate model changes from controller to view and user interactions from view components to the controller. In Swing, a view could be as simple as a JTextField or as complex as a JFrame with a significant set of components/widgets within. Oracle has an overview doc on the pattern [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html)

Lastly, it could just be me, but I haven't seen examples of combined view and controller where I didn't groan and wish for a refactor.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is one of the most popular design pattens not only with Java but with all other object oriented programming languages.

The controller contains the web layer presentation logic such as processing the request and dispatching the response back to the view

The view is responsible for passing the request values to the controller and rendering the returned response back

The model acts closely with the view and controller.

A simple example with the Spring MVC...

1. Dispatcher servlet acts as a Front controller channeling all the requests via it to Related Controllers based on the urls
2. The controller obtains request values from view (JSP) & processes the request values, populates the model accordingly
3. The populated model

   is passed via an ORM framework (Hibernate) to persist the data in
   the database or
   populated model is added back to a session or request scope variable
4. which is used to render the values back in the view (JSP) using JSTL or EL

This is a very simple scenario where a typical web application would use MVC

Answer (score 0):

MVC stands for Model View and Controller. It is a design pattern that separates the business logic, presentation logic and data.Controller acts as an interface between View and Model. Controller intercepts all the incoming requests. Model represents the state of the application(data). It can also have business logic. View represents the presentation i.e. UI(User Interface).